# Объеденить индексы в массиве python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив:

```
data = [('ADAM', 50)],[('WAS', 55)],[('STUDENT', 60)]
```

нужно сделать в таком ввиде:

```
data = [('ADAM', 50), ('WAS', 55), ('STUDENT', 60)]
```

Можно сделать вручную в таком ввиде, но это не правильно, мне нужно динамично:

```
data = data[0] + data[1] + data[2]
```

Comment: `list(chain.from_iterable(data))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [('ADAM', 50)],[('WAS', 55)],[('STUDENT', 60)]

data = sum(data, [])
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 2):

вариант 1:

```
data = [i[0] for i in data]
data = [min(i) for i in data]
data = [max(i) for i in data]
```

вариант 2:

```
data = sum(data, [])
```

вариант 3:

```
data = list(map(max, data))
data = list(map(min, data))
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ)))))))) выручили, голова не соображает